# Which technology to use for automated bookmarking of web pages?

Tags: web-applications, proxy, opera, bookmarks, browser-extension

When browsing the web, I often find myself wishing for "automatic bookmarking" features.

For example, when reading all posts of a blog from the beginning, I want to automatically keep track of which which post I last looked at.

For a different example, I may want to automatically bookmark all pages I visit containing certain keywords.

(By "bookmark",I don't necessarily mean "browser bookmark", just a way to store/process the URL on my local machine so that I can open it at a later time).

Which technology would be best for tackling this problem (I am using Linux, if this matters)? The ones I can think of:

- Browser extensions: The disadvantage is that this is highly depdendent on the browser. I like to use Opera, and am not sure if it can be extended to do this.

  A web application running on localhost, which loads other pages in an iframe: I'm not sure if this is possible because of XSS protection.

  A local proxy server, which filters all HTTP traffic and executes custom scripts when    the URLS or page contents match certain patterns. This seems to be the most flexible option, but also the most complex.

What are your opinions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Browser extensions would be the best option IMO, this use case doesn't require much from the extension API so it should not be too complicated to make such an extension for several browsers. To make sure the data is stored in a safe and portable way, I'd look for or write an extension that integrates with some online bookmarking service.

Answer (score 0):

Opera has an extension API, and can be surely extended to do this. You can scan for keywords in the page title, meta info, or the entire body itself, and if it matches your set of keywords, you can store the page url in local storage, and have an interface to show all the saved urls in the extension toolbar window popup.

Check out the following links for opera extensions

- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/getting-started-with-opera-extensions/
- http://www.opera.com/docs/apis/extensions/

There is also the Opera Link API which you might find usefull

- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-the-opera-link-api/
- http://www.opera.com/docs/apis/linkrest/